# Omitting articles in a list of attributes - is the meaning & grammaticality preserved?

Tags: articles, grammaticality, lists

> His athleticism, **an** unmatched awareness of his surroundings, and **an** undying love for the sport are what make him one of the best.

> His athleticism, unmatched awareness of his surroundings, and undying love for the sport are what make him one of the best.

Are both sentences grammatically correct? Do both sentences essentially mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

In the second sentence, the determiner "his" would probably be understood to apply to all three conjuncts in the series. Thus, for the second and third conjuncts, you are basically replacing the indefinite article "an" with the possessive pronoun "his". That is perfectly grammatical, and the meanings of the two sentences are very similar. (In the first sentence, most readers would attribute the "unmatched awareness" and "undying love" to him anyway, so changing "an" to "his" has little semantic effect.)

However, there is another issue. Conjuncts should in general be parallel in form, but in the first sentence the conjuncts' determiners differ. (The first is "his" while the others are "an".) Therefore, most people would probably consider the second sentence preferable to the first.